# How to get the hostname of a service in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I need the hostname of the service lensespostgres-postgresql, but I get an error:

```
$ kubectl get services -n default                                                                                              
NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
kubernetes                           ClusterIP   ........     <none>        443/TCP    20m
lensespostgres-postgresql            ClusterIP   ........     <none>        5432/TCP   14m
lensespostgres-postgresql-headless   ClusterIP   None         <none>        5432/TCP   14m
$ ping lensespostgres-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local
ping: lensespostgres-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

It appears multiple misunderstandings are at play here.

First of all where are you running the `kubectl` command from and therefore the `ping` command from?

The two most likely scenarios are either a client device (e.g. laptop) or from an infra/master node. In both cases, without some network forwarding they wont have access to the same network as `ClusterIP` which is typically accessible from a worker node.

So the FQDN for the service you have selected is correct, it's just your running `ping` from the wrong place. Your options are 3 fold:

1. Forward the IP range of the *worker nodes* to your client device with the DNS e.g. using something like `sshuttle`
2. Run the `ping` command from a worker node.
3. Deploy another container (preferably in a different `namespace`) and ping from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are prettier ways, but this gives you the answer

```
kubectl get services -o json | grep kubernetes.fqdn
```